# Help with selecting the domain in the integral when calculating the mean of two random variables

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

I once again need your precious help ! I am studying for the upcoming semester and I have a difficulty in selecting the domain in the integral when calculating the mean  of two  random variables. Here is my problem : 
Compute $E(XY)$ when $f_{X|Y}(x,y)=1,\;\text{if}\; 0<\frac{y}{2}<x<1$ and zero elsewhere.

I do not know from where to where to calculate each integral... I know the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$ but I can't get it right... Please if you have the time explain me how to do this. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Are you given the conditional density $f_{X|Y}$ or the joint density $f_{X,Y}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to write down the joint density $f_{X,Y}$ as a function defined everywhere, in the present case, for every $(x,y)$,
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\mathbf 1_{0<y/2<x<1}.
$$
The second step is to apply the definition, in the present case,
$$
E[XY]=\iint_{\mathbb R^2} xy\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\iint_{\mathbb R^2} xy\,\mathbf 1_{0<y/2<x<1}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$
Next, one chooses to integrate first with respect to $y$ then with respect to $x$, or the other way round, for example,
$$
\mathbf 1_{0<y/2<x<1}=\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\,\mathbf 1_{0<y<2x},
$$
hence
$$
E[XY]=\int_0^1x\left(\int_0^{2x}y\mathrm dy\right)\mathrm dx=\int_0^1x\left(2x^2\right)\mathrm dx=\left.\tfrac12x^4\right|_0^1=\tfrac12.
$$

Comment: Oh ! Thank you very much! I was taking $0<y<2x$ and $\frac{y}{2}<1$... So in such cases we expess one variable in relation to the other as $0<y<2x$ and the other free of the previous one as $0<x<1$ because we have the restriction between them in our fist inequality?